# Can I avoid referencing + dereferencing the hash returned from a map operation?

Tags: perl, idioms, dereference

I've got an array of hashes. I want the a list of the values in a key of those hashes based on the uniqueness of another key.

```
my @obs = ({
   value => 'three',
   id => 3
},{
   value => 'one-2',
   id => 1
},{
   value => 'one',
   id => 1
});
# This works, prints "one\nthree"
say for values %{{ map { $_->{id} => $_->{value} } @obs }};
```

Can I avoid the reference + dereference bit around the `map`? At first I tried just calling `values` directly on the return from `map` but Perl won't have it:

> Type of arg 1 to values must be hash (not map iterator) at script\workbench.pl line 55, near "@obs ;"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `values` really, really wants a hash to operate on.  That's because it's special: it clears the place holder used by `each`.  It needs an actual object to clear that on.

You can go one of two ways here.  First, if you don't like the ref/deref, you could just pull the creation of the temporary hash out of the one-liner (please pick a better name than `%h` for your actual code):

```
my %h = map { $_->{id} => $_->{value} }  @obs;
say for values %h;
```

If you don't want `%h` to hang around, just drop it into a temporary block:

```
...code code code...
{
    my %h = map { $_->{id} => $_->{value} }  @obs;
    say for values %h;
}
...code code code...
```

Another approach could be to emulate what your temporary hash creation and `values` is doing:

```
my %seen;
for ( reverse @obs ) { say $_->{value} unless $seen{$_->{id}}++ }
```

What really matters is what you're going to be doing with this data.  If you just need the values of your inverted hash just once, then your one-liner may be the best solution.  If you need this data (id & value) later on, then create the actual hash and use that -- don't do this transform more than once just so that you can keep them as one-liners.

Without further context, it's hard to give advice on which approach to take.

Comment: I believe that David Golden is working on making things like `values`, `each`, `keys`, etc work on references. It's in 5.13 (dev releases) and should be in 5.14 (production release).

Comment: @mpeters, There is some matter of debate due to ambiguities from operator overloading, so some of the features might be marked experiemental in 5.14.

Answer (score 1):

If `values` were to work on a list, it would take every second element of that list. So

```
say for values %{{ map { $_->{id} => $_->{value} } @obs }};
```

would be

```
say for every_odd map { $_->{id} => $_->{value} } @obs;
```

Now, it's entirely possible to write such a function, but it's simply not needed in this case. One can simply do

```
say for map { $_->{value} } @obs;
```

And that simplifies to

```
say $_->{value} for @obs;
```

One catch: By not using a hash, you don't eliminate duplicates.